# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while solving leetcode question

Tags: java, arrays, heap-memory

https://leetcode.com/problems/k-th-symbol-in-grammar/

I was solving the above leetcode question, here is my solution it runs perfectly except for the test case where `n = 30, k = 434991989` in which it shows java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

```
public class kthGrammer{

    public static void rowGenerator(int n, int[] row, int num){
        if(n == num)
            return;
        int start = (row.length / 2) - (int)Math.pow(2, num - 1);
        int pStart = (row.length / 2) - (int)Math.round(Math.pow(2, num - 3));
        while(pStart <= (row.length / 2) + (int)Math.pow(2, num - 3)){
            if(row[pStart] == 0){
                row[start++] = 0;
                row[start++] = 1;
            }
            else{
                row[start++] = 1;
                row[start++] = 0;
            }
            ++pStart;
        }
        rowGenerator(n, row, num + 1);
        return;
    }
    
    public static int kthGrammar(int n, int k) {
        int[] row = new int[(int)Math.pow(2,n - 1)];
        row[row.length / 2] = 0;
        rowGenerator(n, row, 1);
        return row[k - 1];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\nAnswer: " + kthGrammar(30, 434991989));
        // System.out.println("\nAnswer: " + kthGrammar(2, 1));
        // System.out.println("\nAnswer: " + kthGrammar(2, 2));
        // System.out.println("\nAnswer: " + kthGrammar(3, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: You either need to find a mathematically inspired shortcut or you need to get rid of the recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

Resources like LeetCode design their questions in the way that solution can rarely be achieved by using straight-forward approach (due to memory or CPU limitations), so some algorithmic research should be done to get the optimal solution. In your code you generate the whole row set, which is kinda big - 30th row contains 2^30 elements, 29th row contains 2^29 elements, and so on. Moreover if N would be e.g. 1000 than the whole structure wouldn't fit into the memory of entire computer cluster. That's why you get `OutOfMemoryError`

I can just give you a hint:
The idea behind this algorithm is that each row is twice bigger than the previous. So K-th element in R-th row is a "parent" of 2 elements in next row (R+1-th), and that elements have 2K-1 and 2K indices. This forms a pattern, so you can iterate backwards from Nth row by dividing current K by 2 each time until you reach 1st row, and doing some checks.